# get all the User fields to display on the profile page in template in django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-generic-views, django-models

I want to iterate through `User` model and the `UserProfile` model that is attached to `User` to display all the information about the User in a profile page such as

```
UserName:
FirstName:
LastName:
Date of Birth:
.....
```

Is there a generic templateView, that I can use to pass the model and gets its fields displayed on template. Reading many SO articles, I tried this:

```
 ##display user fields
    {% for field in User._meta.get_all_field_names() %}
       <p> {{ field }} : {{ getatttr(field,user) }} </p>
     {% endfor %}
     ## display Userprofile fields
     {for field in User.profile._meta.get_all_field_names() %}
          <p> {{ field }} : {{ getatttr(field,user.profile) }} </p>
     {% endfor %}
```

This does not work:
in fact, I tried only to display all the fields and not its values first:

```
{% for field in User._meta.get_all_field_names() %}
        <p> {{ field }} </p>
     {% endfor %}
```

but I get this error: `Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores: 'User._meta.get_all_field_names'`

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can push this code to your view, and use the handy `django.forms.models.model_to_dict` function to get a dictionary of fields to values for `user` and `user.profile`

views.py:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

class UserDetailView(DetailView):

    model = User

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_attr_map'] = model_to_dict(self.object)
        context['userprofile_attr_map'] = model_to_dict(self.object.profile)
        return context
```

template.html:

```
{% for k, v in user_attr_map.items %}
    <p> {{ k }} : {{ v }} </p>
{% endfor %}
{% for k, v in userprofile_attr_map.items %}
    <p> {{ k }} : {{ v }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: great, this helped a lot.is it possible to remove fields such as `is_superuser`, `is_staff` etc

Comment: yep, you can pass a list of fields to the the keyword argument `exclude` to model_to_dict. 

`context['user_attr_map'] = model_to_dict(self.object, exclude=['is_superuser', 'is_staff'])

the method signature is here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L112

Comment: Thanks that worked. Is there a way to display all the User details for a user to edit after they are logged in such as email, password, first name, last name etc but not UserName..

Comment: I tried this `{% for field, value in userprofile_attr_map.items %}
    <p> {{ field }} : {{ value|yesno:"-----" }} </p>
{% endfor %}` but it is not displaying yes/no. why is that?

Comment: Hm, is that the correct way to use the "yesno" filter? I think it takes in string with 3 comma separated values, like here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno

Comment: Thanks again. that helped. do you have any thought above my previous comment?